# Asking help to optimize this time-consuming find with two chmod command per file

Tags: linux, permissions

I've this command in a .sh file

```
sudo find $PROJECT_ROOT -type f \
     -exec sudo chmod ugo-x '{}' \; \
     -exec sudo chmod go-w '{}' \;
```

As you can see, foreach file I need to remove write permission for group and other, leaving 'as is' the eventual write permission for the user.

AND remove execute permission for every one.

I ask you if there is a way to optimize this... I've not a lot of experience of chmod but this is time consuming: 4-5 minute per projecct folder, for each of our 41 actual projects and this must be executed 2 times per week. (Please do not ask WHY, it's not important, I must DO it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Sisir's answer, the first thing you can do is use "+" instead of ";" in the find command. This makes it run one single command on all matching files instead of one command per file:

```
sudo find $PROJECT_ROOT -type f -exec chmod a-x,go-w '{}' +
```

If the projects contain too many files (there are limits on command line length) you can still use one single `chmod` per directory with a small additional script:

```
#! /bin/bash
# chmod's all files in the $1 directory
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec chmod a-x,go-w {} +
```

and then:

```
sudo find $PROJECT_ROOT -type d -exec chmod_script {} \;
```

(btw, I don't think you need a `sudo` on the command executed by `find`, it should normally inherit the userid of `find`?)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I could combine multiple variations of permissions in a single CHMOD command.I'm trying. I'll reply you soon with esits

Comment: Wow ! Totale mid time per project is now 52% of the previous.  Thanks !
Also, I confirm we don't need "sudo over sudo".

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the command as follows and then check if it improves the performance:

```
sudo find $PROJECT_ROOT -type f -exec sudo chmod a-x,go-w '{}' \;
```